# Replacing configuration values in publish stage gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I have worked on Jenkins pipeline, but new to GitLab CI/CD.
While deploying to UAT and Production environments in jenkins pipeline, I update the web.config for a (.Net project) file by replacing the placeholders (e.g. Keyname:"****Placeholder****") with actual values stored in a json (e.g. **Placeholder**: Value) file specific to an environment. I was doing it by using groovy replace method(`replace("__"+"$key"+"__", "$value")`), by matching the **$value** string from json into **$key** in web.config file.
How can I achieve the same in GitLab publish stage while deploying the artifacts onto UAT/Production servers?

Comment: So the target key and value come from the JSON, is that set in stone? Where does the JSON come from? GitLab.com or self-hosted? What kind of runners do you use?

Comment: For jenkins pipeline, I was picking the config json file stored in GitLab repo created for the pipelines. I am having self-hosted GitLab and Shared runners on-premise VM.

Comment: What OS are your runners on? Have you considered installing "plain" Groovy on the runner, adapt your script to it and use that to run? Or do you maybe have experience in other (scripting) languages?

Comment: I am using Windows. I haven't installed groovy on the runner. Just was thinking if their is an built-in option to achieve this in GitLab CI/CD.